# If new is a pointer, that stores the hexadecimal address of the new node, why does new still refer to the node?

Tags: pointers

If new is a pointer, that stores the hexadecimal address of the new node, why shouldn't it be *new->n=n or *new.n=n instead of new->n=n? Wouldn't *new refer to the actual node?

```
    //insert new node
    void insert(int n)
{
// create new node
node* new = malloc(sizeof(node));

// check for NULL
if (new == NULL)
{
    exit(1);
}
// initialize new node
new->n = n;
new->next = NULL;

// insert new node at head
new->next = head;
head = new;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use `->` notation, that automatically dereferences `new` so that you're dealing with the actual variable, not the pointer.

Btw, please don't use `new` as a variable name :)

Answer (score 0):

`new.n` is an address. 
To change the value of it you need to de-reference it. This can be done like:
`*(new.n)` or `new->n`
The reason for this is because the `*` operator has a very high order of importance in the order of operations. Also you aren't mallocing correct. You need to malloc the `sizeof(struct node)`. You are only allocating the size of a pointer which is either 4 or 8 bytes depending on your architecture.